# Actionscript Left Click Menu

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, chat

I'm making a chatroom in actionscript, and I want to create a left click menu that pulls up some functions like (Ban, Hide, View users profile, etc..)

Any tips on how?  I'd rather not do it through the right click menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener for MouseEvent.CLICK for the container or the element type, for which you want to  see the menu.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I should've been clearer.  I want to now how to actually make the menu.